# Chi-Squared test for statistical analtsis

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, modeling

I'm comparing sonic logs against well logs at 0.5m increments. The soil is identified to be one of 6 categories: SOIL, FILL, GR, SA, SI or OM.

I am attempting to find whether the well data is dependant on the sonic data. (The idea is the sonic data shows the true makeup of the soil, while the good data gives a rough estimate of the soil makeup. I want to do an analysis that shows how close the well data models the sonic data)

My data looks something like this:

The data is set out as follows (although with over 10000 rows)
`SonicData <- c(SOIL, OM, SA, SI,GR,SA,SA,SA)`
`WellData <- c(FILL, SA,SA,SA,GR,SA,SA,SA)` 
`Data <- cbind(SonicData,WellData)`

I have tryed using a number of techniques to discover if there data is dependant or not:

1) I tried a chi- squared test as follows:
`chisq.test(Data$SonicData,Data$WellData)`
which came back with this data
data:  Chi.Data
X-squared = 2078.7, df = 25, p-value < 2.2e-16
And this error:
Warning message:
In chisq.test(Data) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

2) I tried simulating the P value, which removed the error, but when analysing the results via subsets eg who the driller was, or what kind of drill was used the p-value was always the same (because it was simulated I assume?) which makes it kind of pointless with regards to more indepth analysis.

3) I then tried:t
`tbl <- table(Data$SonicData,Data$WellData)`
`chisq.test <-(tbl)`
which came up with the same error

4) I then thought maybe there wasnt enough data, so i tried the fisher test:
`fisher.test <- (tbl)`

which came back with this error
Error in fisher.test(tbl) : FEXACT error 501.
The hash table key cannot be computed because the largest key
is larger than the largest representable int.
The algorithm cannot proceed.
Reduce the workspace, consider using 'simulate.p.value=TRUE' or another algorithm.

again, not keen on simulating p...

5) Then I tried the t-test:
`t.test(tbl)`

which gave the results:
    One Sample t-test

data:  Chi.Data
t = 1.867, df = 35, p-value = 0.0703
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  -5.297399 126.575177
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 60.63889

I have no idea why this worked because my data is nominal (I think), and therefore doesn't have a mean...

So from this I have a few questions:
1. Is there something wrong with my data, structure? 
2. am I using the wrong types of analysis? 
3. Which of my attempts is giving the most accurate results and why? 
4. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your first R code `SonicData <- c(SOIL ... ` seems strange, probably you need `cbind` not `c`. Tell us more about the data: Oil well, water well, what kind of well? What are the variables? Show us some plots. I would start out with visualization, not chisquare. Can you share a (link to) (part of ) the data?

Comment: yup sure thing, the data is from here: https://ecan.govt.nz/data/well-search/welldetails/?WellNo=M36/0174 the sonic data is just meant to be an example of what the data looks like, i imported it all from excel so it's just meant to show its character data type stuff thats been catagorised. the wells are bore logs from around christchurch city.

Comment: Ella, please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts.  That will enable you to edit and comment on your post.